# Código QR que muestre detalles de una compra

Tags: php, qr

Tengo el siguiente problema:

He generado un QR pero quiero que ese QR al ser escaneado por alguna app, muestre los detalles de una compra.

Es decir se realiza una compra en el establecimiento y se guarda en la base de datos, al imprimir el ticket se muestran los productos y precios de cada uno de ellos, dentro de este ticket se muestra un QR al final del mismo y al ser escaneado deberá redireccionar a una página web donde se muestren detalles de la compra solo de esa compra (caducidad, iva cobrado por producto, que cajero los atendió, etc.

````
    require ('plugins/qrcode/qrlib.php');
    $dir='imagenes/qr/';

    if(!file_exists($dir)){
        mkdir($dir);
    }

    //DEFINIR NOMBRE ARCHIVO
    $filename=$dir."test1.png";

    $tam = 8;   
    $level = 'M';
    $frameSize = 3;
    $content = '--->PRUEBA DE QR';

    QRcode::png($content,$filename,$level,$tam,$frameSize);

    echo '<img src="'.$filename.'">';
?> ```
````

Comment: Tienes el código que arroja lo que quieres mostrar tras leer el QR?

Comment: Pues no sé qué problema tienes, yo lo veo muy claro. Genera un código que contenga un enlace con un parámetro al final como el id de la transacción y recógelo en el backend para buscarlo en la base de datos.

Comment: @JeanGotopo por ahora tengo esto ```include ('DataBase/conexion.php');
    $sentencia->prepare("SELECT * FROM reparacion");
    $sentencia->execute();
    $reparacion=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($reparacion as $estado):
        echo $estado['id_reparacion'];
    endforeach; ```

Comment: @MarcosRodríguez no lo había pensado lo intentare muchas gracias

Comment: @MarcosRodríguez no lo había pensado lo intentare muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Aún necesitas ayuda con esto? @ArturoLucasJr.